# jquery.mb.YTPlayer.js not working after initial page load with InstantClick.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, pjax, ytplayer

Is there any way to make [jquery.mb.YTPlayer.js](https://github.com/pupunzi/jquery.mb.YTPlayer) work after initial page load with [InstantClick.js](http://instantclick.io/)?

The plugin works fine on initial page load, but after that it doesn't work anymore.

Here is how I originally initialized it, works fine on page load but not after further navigation:

**app.js**

```
InstantClick.on('change', function() {
        $(".player").mb_YTPlayer();
});
```

I then spent hours on trying to debug and ended up with something like this:

**app.js**

```
InstantClick.on('change', function() {
    if ($(".mbYTP_wrapper")[0]){
        $(".player").playerDestroy();
        console.log('destroyed');
    }
    if (window.YT) {
        console.log(window.YT);
    }

    $(".player").mb_YTPlayer();
});
```

in **jquery.mb.YTPlayer.js** I tried adding this to *.playerDestroy*:

```
playerDestroy: function () {
        jQuery("#YTAPI").remove();
}
```

On the initial page load the object **window.YT** doesn't exist of course, but then after the first page navigation I get 1 Object, then I get 2 Objects for 1 navigation, then I get 3 objects and so on..  The picture below is after 4 page navigations, 10 **window.YT** objects.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had checked both plugins you use, and concluded that the problem is with your codes getting reloaded on every navigation.

To tackle that problem, try using `data-no-instant` attribute for scripts which you need to load only once. That may include following:

> Youtube widget: `<script type="text/javascript" id="www-widgetapi-script" src="https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vflr-TgN1/www-widgetapi.js" async="" data-no-instant></script>`
>
> Youtube API: `<script src="https://www.youtube.com/player_api?v=2.7.6" id="YTAPI" data-no-instant></script>`
>
> JQuery library: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.js" data-no-instant></script>`
>
> YT Player plugin: `<script type="text/javascript" src="inc/jquery.mb.YTPlayer.js" data-no-instant></script>`
>
> InstantClick plugin: `<script src="instantclick.min.js" data-no-instant></script>`
>
> Put Following Codes Too inside: `<script data-no-instant></script>`

Also destroy your YT Player instance on mouseup and touchend events.

```
$(body).on('mouseup touchend',".player",function(){
    $(".player").playerDestroy();
});
```

And re-init the YT Player on InstantClick event `change`.

```
InstantClick.on('change',function(){
    $(".player").mb_YTPlayer();
});
```

Should you do that, I think the problem should be resolved.